# AWS Lambda Function to Start/Stop Instances based on CPU Utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to ask if I can create a Lambda function to start an additional instance when the average CPU utilization of the existing nodes is over a certain threshold?

For example, I have four instances currently started. I want to have a lambda to start an additional instance when the average utilization is over 90% for the four started instance.

Also, I want to stop one of them when the utilization is under 40%.

Comment: Why don't you use auto scaling group?

Comment: What taskiner said coupled with scaling rules triggered by CloudWatch alarms for CPU.

Comment: It is because we use these instances for OpenShift and don't know whether it is compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS CloudWatch to start/stop EC2 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458989/aws-cloudwatch-to-start-stop-ec2-instances)